# CoffeeScript, prototypal inheritance, and constructors

Tags: javascript, constructor, coffeescript, prototype

In CoffeeScript, it seems like the superclasses constructor is not called when you instantiate the subclass.

Is there a way around this?

Here is an example:

```
class A
    element = null

    constructor: ->
        element = document.createElement "div"

    hide: =>
        element.style.display = "none"

class B extends A
    constructor: ->
        @hide() #error!
```

I would expect the constructor of `A` to be called first, then `B`'s constructor. If `B` then calls the `hide` method, it should hide the element that was created in `A`'s constructor instead of saying that `element` is null.

Thanks!

Comment: I agree that this seems to be a bug in coffeescript. Have you created an issue for it?

Answer (score 5):

I think you need to call super in the Subclass

```
class A
    element = null

    constructor: ->
        element = document.createElement "div"

    hide: =>
        element.style.display = "none"

class B extends A
    constructor: ->
        super
        @hide() #error!
```

Comment: Yes, I tried that but it seems like it copies the functions to `B`, defeating the purpose of the prototype chain. Am I mistaken?

Comment: I must admit I never have looked into the generated __extends function but it seems to me that it does create the correct prototype chain.

Comment: @tau It does that even if you don't call super. What is your point? All the chains are there: `b = new B()` `A::hello = -> "Hello"` `alert b.hello()`

Comment: If I inspect the objects in Chrome, both the sub and superclass have their own `hide` methods. Is that what it should say? I would expect the `hide` method to show up only in the superclasses `__proto__` property, but I might be misunderstanding Chrome. I thought the functions should only exist in the superclass and not show up under the subclass. Here's an example:

Comment: class A
        constructor: ->

        test: =>
            alert 'lol'

    class B extends A
        constructor: ->

    b = new B()
    b.test()
    console.log b